# How can I select all copy from vim and paste to other program e.g. mail client?

Tags: vim, x11, copy-paste

How can I do the following?

Copy all text from vim and paste it to an external program e.g. mail Outlook?  I tried `+y` and `gg*yG` but the paste does not work.

Comment: If vim is built with X support, then you should be able to paste into other apps: check with: `vim --version | grep clipboard`

Comment: Then see `:help clipboard`.  In general you should be able to just plain cut 'n' paste with the mouse, although this can get messed up with TUI vim (but not gvim).

Comment: What's _mail Outlook_?

Comment: Are you running a text mode Vim or Gvim? What's “mail Outlook”? Are you running vim in Cygwin? Or are you running Outlook in a virtual machine? Or are both running on OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires vim to have X11 clipboard integration. You can check this by doing `vim --version` and looking for `+xterm_clipboard` (`+clipboard` is not it, that's for using the GUI, which may actually be what you're after, the question doesn't specify GUI or terminal).

If you don't have `+xterm_clipboard`, you'll need to get a version of vim that does have it (or recompile yourself).

If you do have it, then awesome. Lets continue.

X11 has 2 "clipboards". There's the select buffer, and then the real clipboard. The select buffer is the highlight/middle_click thing. The clipboard is the normal CTRL+C/CTRL+V.
To copy the current line into the selection buffer, do `"*yy`. (yes, that's shift+quote shift+8 y y)
To copy into the clipboard, do `"+yy`.
*(you can use other selection specifiers, like `"+yG`, or `"+y` in visual mode)*

If you want to make one of these the default, so you can just do `yy`, without the `"+`/`"*` bit, you can add one of the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

or

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

---

You didn't specify if you were accessing the machine remotely, but if so you can still do this, but you will need X11 forwarding turned on and working in SSH. I will warn you however that it can cause vim to take several seconds to start up.